# Do automatic cars shift gears even if the wheels are slipping?

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission

When cars slip in the snow for example, if you apply full gas will the transmission shift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, old cars for sure.  There are plenty of YouTube videos of power braking where you can hear the tranny upshifting.  I'm not sure about newer cars that might have computerized stability control (ESP) that limits shifting.